# Simple question about the Gagliardo Niremberg interpolation inequality

Tags: sobolev-spaces

Consider  the Gagliardo Niremberg interpolation inequality :

---

(Gagliardo Niremberg interpolation inequality)Let $q,r$ be any numbers satisfying $1 \leq q, r \leq \infty $ and let $j,m$ be any integers satisfying $0 \leq j < m$. If u is any function in $C^{m}_{0}(R^n)$ then

$$ || D^j u ||_p \leq C || D^m u ||_{r}^{a} ||u ||_{q}^{1-a}$$

where $$\frac{1}{p} = \frac{j}{n} + a (\frac{1}{r} - \frac{m}{n}) + (1-a) \frac{1}{q}$$

where $C$ is a constant depending only in n,m,j,q,r,a with the following excepetion:

If $m -j - \frac{n}{r}$ is a nonnegative integer, then the inequality is asserted for $j/m \leq a <1$.

---

With the Gagliardo Niremberg interpolation inequality  i am trying to prove this:

$$ || u||_{2 \sigma + 2}^{2 \sigma + 2} \leq C || u||_{H^1(R^n)}^{\sigma N} || u||_2^{2 + \sigma(2-N)}, \forall u \in H^{1}(R^n)$$
where $0 <\sigma < \frac{2}{N-2}$.

Someone can give me a hand?

thanks in advance!

Comment: I do not understand what are you asking.

Comment: sorry. now i writed better the question =)

Comment: There is no problem here. First, replace $N$ by $n$. Second, notice that $j=0$, $m=1$, $q=r=2$, $p=2\sigma+2$. Then calculate $a$, and here you are.